# Angular change Cell Value Conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a grid displaying this data, I want to change the table data based upon cell value if cell values are 1 I have to display tick mark else cell value
can you please help me

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="Monday">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> M </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="{'make-tick': element.Monday == '1'}"
        [ngClass]="{'make-gold': element.Monday == '0'}"> {{ element.Monday}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as an image. Thank you.

Comment: also don't add it in the comments. Edit your question.

Comment: thank you can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `*ngIf` to do that.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Monday">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> M </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" 
      [ngClass]="{'make-tick': element.Monday == '1', 'make-gold': element.Monday == '0'}">
    <ng-container *ngIf="element.Monday != '1'; else tick">
      {{element.Monday}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #tick><!-- markup for tick --></ng-template>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you G.Tranter that helped me a lot can you please help me how this below line                    "<ng-template #tick><!-- markup for tick --></ng-template>"  works

Comment: It is part of the `*ngIf="element.Monday != '1'; else tick"` statement. When the condition is false (`else`), the template with the matching name (`tick`) is rendered. See https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf.